Do migraine auras orient to the head or to the real world?
E.g. Consider two migraine events:
Event A:  An aural pattern that occupies the middle of the visual field with the most "interesting" part being a strong horizontal line just below center of the field.  When the person tilts his head, the pattern stays in the same part of the visual field in the same orientation.
Event B:  As above but the distortion maintains orientation to the world.  As hte patient tilts his head to the left, the image rotates in the visual field so that hte horizotal intereesting bit remains parallel to the horizon.
Both events are under an hour.
Are B type events still auras or is this  another class of problems in neurology?
